# Comparing 2 arrays with all items

Tags: java, arrays

So I have this code

```
String[] List1 = {"Item1","Item2", "item3"};
String[] List2 = {};
int[] anArray;
anArray = new int[5];
Random rand = new Random();

String cat;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
    int  n = rand.nextInt(3) + 0;           
    anArray[i] = n;

    System.out.println(List1[n]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (List1[i] == List1[anArray[i]]) {
        System.out.println("101"); 
    }
}
```

Basically what it does it make an array with 3 items, and makes a random number prints 3 random items.

I wanted to find a way to make each item off the original array to compare off the second array. But It can't be a simple .

The issue with this is it only compares the items in order,
How do i compare each item off an array off each item.

Reason I don't do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (List1[1] == List1[anArray[i]]) {
        System.out.println("101");

    }
}
```

Is because the actual code I'm using had like 100 items in the array.

Is there anyway to compare all items off each other?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question wasn't tagged with the language you are using, which means it likely won't be seen by users with the knowledge required to help you. I have fixed that for you. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines on how to ask a good question.

Comment: So you compare an item in the list to a random item in the same list, and you do that... oddly.  Why? Can you expand on `Is there anyway to compare all items off each other?`?  It's not clear what that means.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for nested for-loops?